# custom UITableViewCell memory leak when calling reloadData

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that's loading some custom UITableViewCells. These custom cells alloc a few UIButtons, and add those buttons to the custom cell's contentView. When repeatedly calling reloadData on the tableView, it seems these UIButtons are slowly leaking memory. I am using ARC, iOS 7.

Here's where the cell is created:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PostCell";
    PostCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PostCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And here's the init method for the custom cell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.height = 0;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [self addInteractionContainer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And finally the addInteractionContainer method (if I don't call this method, I don't see a leak):

```
- (void)addInteractionContainer {
    //interaction container
    UIView* interactionContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 80)];
    [interactionContainer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor ProseSepiaColor]];

    //like button
    LikeButton* likeButton = [[LikeButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 75, 30) liked:([post.yourVote intValue] > 0)];
    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likePost:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [interactionContainer addSubview:likeButton];

    //comment button
    CommentButton* commentButton = [[CommentButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(likeButton.frame.origin.x + likeButton.frame.size.width + 10,
                                                           10, 105, 30)];
    [commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(segueToComments:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [commentButton setNumComments:self.post.numComments];
    [interactionContainer addSubview:commentButton];
    [self.contentView addSubview:interactionContainer];
    self.height += interactionContainer.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: as you say when you don't call addInteractionContainer you don't leak.can you test using UIButton, so that we can confirm that there is something wrong with subclassing of Like button class or comment class

Comment: You can use the leaks instrument to try and identify the problem, but your addInteractionContainer doesn't look "right". It is adding event handlers and referencing data - "self.post.numComments" even though this property can't have been set at this point. You should just add the UI elements in your cells constructor and expose these via properties. You can then add the action handler and contents in your tableview controller

Comment: I did try using just a basic UIButton with no additional data, same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PostCell";
    PostCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell!=nil)
{
     cell=nil;
}
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PostCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```